# Bitbucket pipelines are failing on insuficient memmory, while testing with cassandra in docker (Scala)

Tags: docker, cassandra, bitbucket, testcontainers

I have Scala tests that need docker cassandra up and running.

I get one of those depending on configuration

- `Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit.`
- `Container 'docker' exceeded memory limit.`
- Cassandra container OOM

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was cassandra config for the win but also set of bitbucket configurations:

- cassandra env variables, set for test-containers but can be passed to docker in any other way

```
 val container: CassandraContainer = CassandraContainer()
 container.container.addEnv("JVM_OPTS", "-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M")
 container.container.addEnv("HEAP_NEWSIZE", "128M")
 container.container.addEnv("MAX_HEAP_SIZE", "2048M")
 container.start()
```

- bitbucket pipelines

```
options:
  docker: true
  size: 2x # Increase max size to 8GB

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 4096 # Give 4 to docker

...

  - step:
          name: run the tests
          caches:
            - sbt
            - ivy2
          script:
            - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
            # Limit sbt memory usage
            - export SBT_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss4m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
            - sbt -v scalafmtSbtCheck scalafmtCheck +compile +test
          services:
            - docker
```